# How to set a different image for the background of each slide of the powerpoint using JAVA Apache POI?

Tags: java, background, apache-poi, powerpoint

I am trying to create a powerpoint and set a different image as background for each slide of my powerpoint. Unfortunatly, even if I success to change the background of my powerpoint by an image, my background will always be the last image of the loop.

In the code every image is name 'image('i')' with i the number of the image and I want the first image to be the background of the first slide, the second image the background of the second slide and etc...

If someone can help me please.
Thanks

```
//Find number of slides to create
int nbSlide = new File(directoryScreen).listFiles().length;
//creating a new empty slide show
XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow();
XSLFSlideMaster slideMaster = ppt.getSlideMasters().get(0);
List<XSLFSlideLayout> slides = new ArrayList<XSLFSlideLayout>();
for(int i=1; i<=nbSlide; i++) 
   XSLFPictureData pd = ppt.addPicture(new 
   File(directoryScreen+"\\image"+i+".png"), PictureType.PNG);
   XSLFSlideLayout slidelayout = slideMaster.getLayout(SlideLayout.BLANK);
   XSLFPictureShape ps = slidelayout.createPicture(pd);
   ps.setAnchor(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 960, 540));
   slides.add(slidelayout);
}
for(int i=0; i<nbSlide; i++) {
   XSLFSlide sl = ppt.createSlide(slides.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing with your code is not setting background pictures but setting picture shapes on always the same slide layout named "Blank". A slide master provides only one slide layout named "Blank", so the `slideMaster.getLayout(SlideLayout.BLANK)` always gets this same one slide layout.

When the need is really setting background pictures to the slides then this must be done using the background properties of the slides.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.presentationml.x2006.main.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.*;

import java.awt.Dimension;

public class CreatePPTXSheetsDifferentBackgroundPictures {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow();
  XSLFPictureData[] pictureDatas = new XSLFPictureData[]{
   slideShow.addPicture(new FileInputStream("Hydrangeas.jpg"), PictureData.PictureType.JPEG),
   slideShow.addPicture(new FileInputStream("Desert.jpg"), PictureData.PictureType.JPEG),
   slideShow.addPicture(new FileInputStream("Chrysanthemum.jpg"), PictureData.PictureType.JPEG)
  };

  // s slides, each having one different background picture out of pictureDatas array
  for (int s = 0; s < pictureDatas.length; s++ ) {
   XSLFSlide slide = slideShow.createSlide();
   CTBackgroundProperties backgroundProperties = slide.getXmlObject().getCSld().addNewBg().addNewBgPr();
   CTBlipFillProperties blipFillProperties = backgroundProperties.addNewBlipFill();
   CTRelativeRect ctRelativeRect = blipFillProperties.addNewStretch().addNewFillRect();
   String idx = slide.addRelation(null, XSLFRelation.IMAGES, pictureDatas[s]).getRelationship().getId();
   CTBlip blib = blipFillProperties.addNewBlip();
   blib.setEmbed(idx);
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreatePPTXSheetsDifferentBackgroundPictures.pptx");
  slideShow.write(out);
  out.close();
 }
}
```

This is the same what `PowerPoint`s GUI is doing when `Format Background` is used.

Each different slide layout also has background properties. So the background properties also could be set on different slide layouts. Different slide layouts can be one out of all possible [SlideLayout](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/SlideLayout.html) per slide master. If done then that background automatically is used on all slides which uses that slide layout.

Comment: Thank  you for your answer. However the program tell me there is an error in fact the line : `CTRelativeRect ctRelativeRect = blipFillProperties.addNewStretch().addNewFillRect();` send me this error message : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.impl.CTRelativeRectImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.poi.sl.draw.binding.CTRelativeRect
 at CreatePPTX.pptx(CreatePPTX.java:52)`. They suggest I had cast to (CTRelativeRect) but even with adding the cast the programm stop at this line. DO you have an idea why ? Thanks again

Comment: My code does not import `org.apache.poi.sl.draw.binding.*` at all. But your code seems importing `org.apache.poi.sl.draw.binding.*`. Why? My `CTRelativeRect` is `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTRelativeRect`. So do using the fully-qualified name. Or, since the `CTRelativeRect` is not needed further in the code, simply do `blipFillProperties.addNewStretch().addNewFillRect();` instead of `CTRelativeRect ctRelativeRect = blipFillProperties.addNewStretch().addNewFillRect();`.